# upsource usage in project with code generation

Tags: upsource

I'm trying to use Upsource code review tool for my java/maven project.
We are using JOOQ, and it produces a lot of generated classes during project compilation, and these classes are not stored in vcs.
And if some class uses JOOQ-generated classes, then code analyse shows errors (Can't resolve symbol).
Is it's possible to fix this problem in a some way?
I just don't understand, does upsource build the project internally, or not. If it does, then where I can find the build log?